# Controlling Nanobots in the Bloodstream as a Form of Torture?

Tags: internal-consistency, nanotechnology, bio-mechanics, torture

An oppressive government entity roughly 70 years in the future has access to elite--albeit experimental--technology. One such technology is a brain chip that allows its soldiers to control simple machines. It's fairly limited to just an on/off process, like we see in some technology today (I think of games like Mindflex).

If nanobots were introduced to a victim's bloodstream, could an on/off process be able to contract nanobots in areas of the body to stop a victim's heart, deflate his lungs, or rupture a spleen? Remember, it's only an on/off process, so they wouldn't necessarily be able to control the nanobots to specific places or do specific things. Only simple actions like "contract/relax," etc.

Comment: Are you going for pain? Or psychological I almost died?

Comment: You can do these things by straightforward medical means (e.g. drugs, gas, electrical).  Why complicate life with nanobots ?  In the "near" future more sophisticated devices might be possible to implement the simple methods, but nanobots just seems overly complex to me.  Also the things you mention (stopping a heart, rupturing a spleen) are likely to kill someone very quickly - they're really useless as torture as you really want the victim to live to the point they *want* to die (and longer).  Simple electrical shocks work better.

Comment: Hello Jay.  I apologize that it's hard to describe this kind of question with a simple title, but it's type is something like this: "you're asking about whether or not a fictional technology can be used to do something.  The answer is always 'yes' because it's your story.  If you ask whether or not it's believable, the answer is also 'yes' because you control how your story is presented."  This leads me to ask, what are you actually interested in knowing?

Comment: Garret -- probably both. Pain would be the main factor, though, since the government agency typically keeps its victims alive.

Comment: StephenG -- you make a fair point, because nanobots seem to be overwhelmingly complex. I'd love to simplify it. So I guess I'm mainly looking for a way to manipulate those organs instantaneously--think of Darth Vader crushing a throat and then letting go when he's made his point. Ex: squeeze a heart until a victim *thinks* he may die, cause the stomach to contract so painfully a victim could vomit, etc.

Comment: JBH, I'm interested to know if this is scientifically or medically possible in a near future. Essentially, if I go through with this idea, I don't want a reader to roll his eyes and say "Wow, that would never happen. This is unrealistic." So can nanotech, or some other agent in the bloodstream, contract or relax instantaneously with a "flip of a switch"?

Comment: True solitary confinement where food is slid to them remotely would be a more efficient form of torture.

Comment: use the @ then the name to the people you want to talk to like so @Jay Dee

Comment: @JayDee (note the use of the "@" to notify users of your comment), we can't build nanobots.  We don't have nanotech.  Anything we tell you is an outlandish guess.  You're asking for facts where none exist.  The question isn't "can we do it?" it's "can I believably write about it?"  That's not a function of detail (there isn't any), it's a function of your use of language.

Answer (score 2):

The nanotech won't try to stop someone's heart or anything that could risk the victim's life. Instead, when activated, it turns into a synthetic histamine, that bonds to the same receptors as the natural stuff, just stronger. Histamine is a chemical involved with itching, commonly from bug bites.

Imagine, if you would, the ability to make the victim feel like their entire body is covered with bug bites, at will. Well, not quite at will, as the nanotech will be floating in the bloodstream and need a moment to come across a receptor. The reverse will be instant, though, as the nanotech will no longer fit into the receptor, ending the effect.